# Can't see "+" sign in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

I wish to download new Python packages into PyCharm but I cannot see the "+" sign in the interpreter tab. Please advise on what I should do to be able to view it so that I can continue the steps to download Python packages. I am using a Mac btw.

Thanks!

Comment: What does that ellipsis button do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on the `...` button to the right of `Project Interpreter`? I've looked on both Windows and Linux and they both have a gear wheel with +/- buttons. Perhaps for some reason they pulled the +/- functionality into the `...` on Macs. On both Windows and Linux, my gear wheel gives me `Add Local, Add Remote, Create VirtualEnv, More...`. Do you see anything different? What version of Pycharm are you using?